# Wrapper for LeagueAPI in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, wrapper

**Full code is here:** https://github.com/LionelBergen/LeagueReddit

I'm creating a wrapper for the LeagueAPI in Node.js.

This includes methods to call various endpoints and classes to map the outputs & inputs.

'Champion' class is Integer mapped to a name. (output from endpoints)

**Champion.js**

```
const Champion =
{
    266 : 'AATROX',
    103 : 'AHRI',
    84 : 'AKALI',
    12 : 'ALISTAR'
}

module.exports = Champion;
```

'LeagueAccountInfo' contains data returned from an endpoint method.

**LeagueAccountInfo.js**

```
class LeagueAccountInfo
{
    constructor(id, accountId, puuid, name, profileIconId, summonerLevel)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.accountId = accountId;
        this.puuid = puuid;
        this.name = name;
        this.profileIconId = profileIconId;
        this.summonerLevel = summonerLevel;
    }

    static from(json)
    {
        return Object.assign(new LeagueAccountInfo(), json);
    }
}

module.exports = LeagueAccountInfo;
```

Here is the main class:

**LeagueAPI.js**

```
require('./classes');
const https = require('https');

// Riot specifies this as a sample regexp to validate names
// any visible Unicode letter characters, digits (0-9), spaces, underscores, and periods.
const NAME_REGEXP = new RegExp('^[0-9\\p{L} _\\.]+$');

const GET_SUMMONER_BY_NAME_URL = 'https://%region%.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/%name%?api_key=%apikey%';
const GET_CHAMPION_MASTERY_URL = 'https://%region%.api.riotgames.com/lol/champion-mastery/v4/champion-masteries/by-summoner/%name%?api_key=%apikey%';
const GET_CHAMPION_ROTATION_URL = 'https://%region%.api.riotgames.com/lol/platform/v3/champion-rotations?api_key=%apikey%';
const GET_QUEUES_WITH_RANKS_URL = 'https://%region%.api.riotgames.com/lol/league/v4/positional-rank-queues?api_key=%apikey%';
const GET_STATUS_URL = 'https://%region%.api.riotgames.com/lol/status/v3/shard-data?api_key=%apikey%';
const GET_ACTIVE_GAME_URL = 'https://%region%.api.riotgames.com/lol/spectator/v4/active-games/by-summoner/%name%?api_key=%apikey%';
const GET_MATCHLIST_URL = 'https://%region%.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v4/matchlists/by-account/%accountid%?api_key=%apikey%'
const GET_MATCH_URL = 'https://%region%.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v4/matches/%matchid%?api_key=%apikey%';

class LeagueAPI
{
    constructor(apiKey, region)
    {
        this.apiKey = apiKey;
        this.region = region;
    }

    changeRegion(region)
    {
        this.region = region;
    }

    getStatus(callback)
    {
        makeAnHTTPSCall(getURLStatus(this.apiKey, this.region), callback);
    }

    getMatch(matchId, callback)
    {
        makeAnHTTPSCall(getMatchURL(matchId, this.apiKey, this.region), callback);
    }

    getPositionalRankQueues(callback)
    {
        makeAnHTTPSCall(getURLQueuesWithRanks(this.apiKey, this.region), callback);
    }

    getSummonerByName(summonerName, callback)
    {
        makeAnHTTPSCall(getURLSummonerByName(summonerName, this.apiKey, this.region), function(data) {
            callback(LeagueAccountInfo.from(data));
        });
    }

    getActiveGames(accountObj, callback)
    {
        let summonerId = getSummonerIdFromParam(accountObj);

        makeAnHTTPSCall(getURLActiveGames(summonerId, this.apiKey, this.region), callback);
    }

    getMatchList(accountObj, callback)
    {
        let accountId = getAccountIdFromParam(accountObj);

        makeAnHTTPSCall(getURLMatchList(accountId, this.apiKey, this.region), callback);
    }

    getChampionMastery(accountObj, callback)
    {
        let summonerId = getSummonerIdFromParam(accountObj);

        makeAnHTTPSCall(getURLChampionMastery(summonerId, this.apiKey, this.region), function(data) {
            let championMasterObjects = [];
            for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++)
            {
                championMasterObjects.push(ChampionMastery.from(data[i]));
            }
            callback(championMasterObjects);
        });
    }

    getFreeChampionRotation(callback)
    {
        makeAnHTTPSCall(getURLChampRotation(this.apiKey, this.region), function(data) { 
            callback(ChampionRotation.from(data));
        });
    }
}

function getSummonerIdFromParam(param)
{
    summonerId = '';

    if (param instanceof LeagueAccountInfo)
    {
        summonerId = param.id;
    }
    else if (param instanceof String)
    {
        summonerId = param;
    }
    else
    {
        throw 'invalid argument, requires summonerId or LeagueAccountInfo object';
    }

    return summonerId;
}

function getAccountIdFromParam(param)
{
    accountId = '';

    if (param instanceof LeagueAccountInfo)
    {
        accountId = param.accountId;
    }
    else if (param instanceof String)
    {
        accountId = param;
    }
    else
    {
        throw 'invalid argument, requires accountId or LeagueAccountInfo object';
    }

    return accountId;
}

function getMatchURL(matchId, apiKey, region)
{
    return getURLWithRegionAndAPI(GET_MATCH_URL, apiKey, region).replace('%matchid%', matchId);
}

function getURLMatchList(summonerId, apiKey, region)
{
    return getURLWithRegionAndAPI(GET_MATCHLIST_URL, apiKey, region).replace('%accountid%', summonerId);
}

function getURLActiveGames(summonerId, apiKey, region)
{
    return getURLWithRegionAndAPI(GET_ACTIVE_GAME_URL, apiKey, region).replace('%name%', summonerId);
}

function getURLStatus(apiKey, region)
{
    return getURLWithRegionAndAPI(GET_STATUS_URL, apiKey, region);
}

function getURLQueuesWithRanks(apiKey, region)
{
    return getURLWithRegionAndAPI(GET_QUEUES_WITH_RANKS_URL, apiKey, region);
}

function getURLChampionMastery(summonerName, apiKey, region)
{
    return getURLWithRegionAndAPI(GET_CHAMPION_MASTERY_URL, apiKey, region).replace('%name%', summonerName);
}

function getURLSummonerByName(summonerName, apiKey, region)
{
    return getURLWithRegionAndAPI(GET_SUMMONER_BY_NAME_URL, apiKey, region).replace('%name%', summonerName);
}

function getURLChampRotation(apiKey, region)
{
    return getURLWithRegionAndAPI(GET_CHAMPION_ROTATION_URL, apiKey, region);
}

// All endpoint URL's contain APIKey and Region
function getURLWithRegionAndAPI(url, apiKey, region)
{
    return url.replace('%apikey%', apiKey).replace('%region%', region);
}

function hasError(jsonData)
{
    return jsonData.status ? true : false;
}

function makeAnHTTPSCall(URL, callback)
{
    https.get(URL, (resp) => {
      let data = '';

      // A chunk of data has been recieved.
      resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
        data += chunk;
      });

      // The whole response has been received.
      resp.on('end', () => {
            let parsedData = JSON.parse(data);

            if (hasError(parsedData))
            {
                console.log('failed: ');
                console.log(parsedData);
            }
            else
            {
                callback(parsedData);
            }
      });

    // TODO: Errors are important, save to a database or Log file
    }).on("error", (err) => {
      console.log("Error: " + err.message);
    });
}

module.exports = LeagueAPI;
```

I've created a folder with all the of mapping classes in one folder, with an index.js inside of it so I could import it via `require('./classes')`:

```
LeagueAccountInfo = require('./LeagueAccountInfo.js');
ChampionMastery = require('./ChampionMastery.js');
LeagueChampions = require('./Champion.js');
Region = require('./Region.js');
ChampionRotation = require('./ChampionRotation.js');

module.exports = {LeagueAccountInfo, LeagueChampions, ChampionMastery, ChampionRotation, Region}
```

**Note: Code is currently in a working state, but not finished. I plan to add the other endpoint methods & classes after review.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've taken a look at other Node Code Reviews and done some research;

Use Promises instead of Callbacks. This should be an easy change, just implement a Promise in the `makeAnHTTPSCall`mathod and remove all callbacks.

This makes error handling easier and makes the code much easier to follow:

```
// Example usage after implementing Promises
LeagueAPI.getSummonerByName().then(function(data) {
    return LeagueAPI.getMatchList(data);
})
.then(console.log)
.catch(console.log);

// Example method with Promise (makeAnHTTPSCall should also use Promise instead of callback)
getChampionMasteryByChampion(accountObj, championObj)
{
    let summonerId = getSummonerIdFromParam(accountObj);
    let championId = getChampionIdFromParam(championObj);

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        makeAnHTTPSCall(getURLChampionMasteryByChampion(summonerId, championId, this.apiKey, this.region))
        .then(function(data) {
            resolve(ChampionMastery.from(data));
        })
        .catch(reject);
    });
}
```

`Champion` was supposed to be used somewhat like an Enum. Currently for example `Champion.AATROX` would give an error, since '266' is the key, but `Champion.266` is invalid JS and doesn't really make sense anyway. Instead I've used Objects as the values:

```
const Champion =
{
    AATROX: {value: 266, label: 'Aatrox' },
    AHRI: {value: 103, label: 'Ahri' },
    AKALI: {value: 84, label: 'Akali' },
    ALISTAR: {value: 12, label: 'Alistar' },
    findById(id)
    {
        return Object.values(this).find(champ => {return champ.value === id})
    }
}
```

Now `Champion.AATROX` can be used as well as `Champion.findById(266)`.

Comment: I'm marking this as an accepted answer, but am more than willing to mark a different/better answer if someone posts one